# Dygraphs with Angular 13 and Ionic 6

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, dygraphs

I'm trying to use [Dygraphs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dygraphs) in a Ionic app, but I got a blank canvas without data and no errors.

Did someone make it works with recent angular/ionic versions ?

start.page.ts

```js
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import Dygraph from 'dygraphs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-start',
  templateUrl: './start.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./start.page.scss'],
})
export class StartPage implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('graphDiv') graphDiv: ElementRef;

  constructor(private router: Router){}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    new Dygraph(this.graphDiv.nativeElement,
      `Date,A,B
      2016/01/01,10,20
      2016/07/01,20,10
      2016/12/31,40,30
      `);
  }
}
```

start.page.html

```html
<ion-row class="ion-align-items-center">
  <canvas #graphDiv></canvas>
</ion-row>
```

**Edit**

When I just put the div it works fine but with ionic tags it shows blank

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-gfrgu9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: maybe because <ion-row> has a height of zero beacuse the canvas has no height?
try to inspect your HTML or set a height

Comment: I also tried with height
https://pasteboard.co/z26PT2FklZ6t.png

Comment: maybe have a look at this example, they don't use canvas
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dygraph?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Couldn't make it works either, also tried [ng-dygraphs](https://github.com/mpx200/ng-dygraphs) but got dependencies problems